# SignalR chat room with Acknowledgement of message received after saving it to Sql data Base

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Hello every one I am new to signalR I need little help to follow right approach in my chat module .
My Refernce :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room but this article does not uses dataBase.
Steps which I have used to build my chat module are :
1 - Created `chatHub` class inherited from `Hub` class.
2 - On `Connect(string enryptedId)` function in `chatHub` class I am adding to `List<UserDetail>`. 
 
3 - On `SendPrivateMessage(string toData)` I am saving it to database if it saved successfully to dataBase without any exception then sending it to both sender and reciever and binding on their communication messages `<div>`. 
 
Problem in this approach - If after saving it to database if sender got disconnected due to network problem then sender will not recieve message from `chathub` class to client function so  message is not appended to `<div>` which shows user communications but actually message sent successfully. 
Please can any one tell me the right approach to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this, keep in mind its Pseduo code not tested or anything

```
private Dictionary<Guid, TaskCompletionSource<bool>> transactions = new Dictionary<Guid, TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

public Task SendPrivateMessage(string content)
{
    var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var transactionId = Guid.NewGuid();

    transactions[transactionId] = taskCompletion;
    var message = new Message
    {
        TransactionId = transactionId,
        Content = content
    };

    GlobalHost
        .ConnectionManager
        .GetHubContext<MyHub>()
        .Clients
        .Client(connectionId)
        .OnMessage(message); 

    return taskCompletion.Task;
}

public void OnTransactionConfirmed(Guid transactionId)
{
    var taskCompletion = transactions[transactionId];
    transactions.Remove(transactionId);
    taskCompletion.SetResult(true);
}
```

Message is just a DTO

```
public class Message
{
    public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Basically you send a message to the client using the client method called `OnMessage` then you wait asynchronously until client confirms with the Hub method called  `OnTransactionConfirmed`

Using a task makes it easier to work asynchronous  in a synchronous way, the consumer of `SendPrivateMessage` could be asynchronous itself (If its called from a WebApi method or similar).

```
public Task MyWebApiMethod() 
{
   return myChatLogic.SendPrivateMessage("foo");
}
```

Or in a synchronous manner

```
public void MySyncMethod() 
{
   myChatLogic.SendPrivateMessage("foo").Wait(); //Thread will wait here until client asnwers
}
```

**Note**
To make this code failsafe you need to timeout the wait for confirmation and complete the task and remove the transactionId etc

Answer (score 0):

your send message, receive message and display message should be handled separately.  you did well with the send message except that you need to add a datetime stamp generated by the Server (do not use time from client) to each message and store it in sql.  whenever there is a new message received, the Server should send this message to all online senders' and receivers'  client browser or app.

here I said senderS because user A may login using a phone and at the same time login using office desktop browser, if user A send a message to user B mobile phone using the desktop browser, this message should be appear in 3 client device: user A desktop browser, user A mobile phone and user B mobile phone.

for the receiver, whenever go from offline to online, check the last message datetime stored in client side using cookie or file or clientside sqlite or clientside internal storage, with the Server database and get all related messages since last offline by comparing the last message datetime from clientside and message dt from server database.

for the display message, only read from client side storage so that the apps can run offline.

Answer (score -2):

When sending a message, append a random string of 8 characters to the start of the message. On your message received function, cut out the first 8 characters and send those back to the original sender.

If you receive the same characters back from the receiver, then you know that receiver has received the message and has not been disconnected.

You can use this method to generate a random string.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> RandomStrings(
    string allowedChars,
    int minLength,
    int maxLength,
    Random rng)
{
    char[] chars = new char[maxLength];
    int setLength = allowedChars.Length;

    int length = rng.Next(minLength, maxLength + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            chars[i] = allowedChars[rng.Next(setLength)];
        }

        return new string(chars, 0, length);
}
```

you will can call the method like this

```
private string GetRandomStrings(){
    const string AllowedChars =
        "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#@$^*()";
    Random rng = new Random();
    return RandomStrings(AllowedChars, 8, 8, 1, rng)
}
```

Comment: Downvoting this! The answer should actually have the client code demonstrating ACK.